# Preliminaries to start linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, advice

Title says it all, are there also any specific online courses or books you would recommend for the prerequisites?
Thanks

Comment: not much. all modern books i am aware of introduce basic set theory and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how abstract you want it to be. If it's just and introductory course without a ton of abstractions and proofs, then honestly not much is needed as a prereq, maybe some basic calculus. If you want an abstract and proof heavy course then maybe some groups, rings, and fields (these would be necessary for a high level linear algebra course), set theory, and most importantly how to do proofs would probably be necessary. All of that is covered in a college discrete mathematics or introduction to proofs course.

So it's really up to you.

Assuming you know at least calculus then these are some good resources for an introductory course:

Linear Algebra: a geometric approach by T Shiffin and M.R. Adams

The Essence of Linear Algebra by 3blue1brown

For an intermediary course in linear algebra (proof based and abstract but still undergraduate level):

Linear Algebra and its Applications, by Peter D. Lax,

Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler

For a graduate level course in linear algebra (very proof based, very abstract):

Advanced Linear Algebra by Steven Roman

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice book called **Linear Algebra by A.R. Rao and P. Bhimasankaram** for development of theory and for problem book and problem solving tricks you can see **Linear algebra and linear models by R. B. Bapat** but in in these book not cover the topic linear transformation approach and further reading I suggest the book **Matrix Algebra From a Statistician's Perspective by David A. Harville** this book contain huge ammount of topics.

Answer (score 0):

Basic arithmetic and set theory were the only prerequisites for the linear algebra that I learned in undergrad.

Answer (score 0):

To start you can read Stanley Grossman's linear algebra book, it is a basic book that allows you to understand some important concepts and has a number of good exercises and examples. Once you have studied this book, you can read Pita Ruíz's linear algebra book (it is in Spanish, I don't know if it has an English version) this book is of a higher level of difficulty than Stanley and very good.

Also, I suggest Gilbert Strang's text for linear algebra. That book is a treasure.

If you want to dig deeper into the topics, then the ideal is the linear algebra text by S. Friedberg A. Insel L. Spence. I still use the text as a reference for my classes.